# Transformation matrix - Two ways to calculate?

Tags: linear-transformations

I need to undersatand what is the difference between my calculation and class calculation.

Suppose I have a matrix A:[image]

And I need to change its base to be the following:  [image]

So I used this formula and got was the right answer,:

[image]

But in calss we have seen a different way which I do not undersatand why both of them brings the same result, this is the other way, and how she actually calculate it

[image]

Comment: In the future, please take the time to enter important parts of your question as text, using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions, instead of pasting pictures of it. Your question is pretty much incomprehensible without those images, so is inaccessible to people who depend on screen readers. Also, images are neither searchable nor appear in summaries.

Answer (score 1):

Call your basis vectors $\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\}$. The point is that for each $b_i$, we can write $Ab_i$ as a sum of the other basis vectors with some scalar coefficients $c_{ij}$. This looks like:

$$ \begin{array}{c}
Ab_1 = c_{11}b_1+c_{21}b_2+c_{31}b_3+c_{41}b_4 \\
Ab_2 = c_{12}b_1+c_{22}b_2+c_{32}b_3+c_{42}b_4 \\
Ab_3 = c_{13}b_1+c_{23}b_2+c_{33}b_3+c_{43}b_4 \\
Ab_4 = c_{14}b_1+c_{24}b_2+c_{34}b_3+c_{44}b_4
\end{array} \tag{I}$$

If $C$ is the matrix which represents how $A$ acts with respect to the basis $B$, then this means

$$ C = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & c_{14} \\
c_{21} & c_{22} & c_{23} & c_{24} \\
c_{31} & c_{32} & c_{33} & c_{34} \\
c_{41} & c_{42} & c_{43} & c_{44} 
\end{bmatrix} \tag{II}$$

For instance, the first line of $(\mathrm I)$ says that

$$ C \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} c_{11} \\ c_{21} \\ c_{31} \\ c_{41} \end{bmatrix} \tag{III} $$

What your teacher did in class is find the row coefficients in $(\mathrm I)$ and write them as column vectors, then combined them all into the matrix $C$. On the other hand, we can rewrite $(\mathrm I)$ to look like this:

$$ A 
\begin{bmatrix} | & | & | & | \\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 \\ | & | & | & | \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} | & | & | & | \\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 \\ | & | & | & | \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & c_{14} \\
c_{21} & c_{22} & c_{23} & c_{24} \\
c_{31} & c_{32} & c_{33} & c_{34} \\
c_{41} & c_{42} & c_{43} & c_{44} 
\end{bmatrix} $$

The vertical bars signify we are using the $b_i$s for columns. If we write $B$ as the matrix we get using the $b_i$s as columns, we can simply write $AB=BC$. Note when we multiply $AB$ on the left, we apply the matrix $A$ to each column of $B$. Multiply out the matrices on the right to see how this really is just equation $(\mathrm I)$!

But $AB=BC$ means we can calculate $C=B^{-1}AB$, which is the formula you used.